# Через .map() прогнать html

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Читаю документацию по `.map()` и не могу сообразить, как прогнать `html` через него. Если что у меня .jsx Может кто подскажет?

```html
<div className="bg">
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-1">
        <div className="dot dot-1"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-2">
        <div className="dot dot-2"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-3">
        <div className="dot dot-3"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-4">
        <div className="dot dot-4"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-5">
        <div className="dot dot-5"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-6">
        <div className="dot dot-6"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-7">
        <div className="dot dot-7"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-8">
        <div className="dot dot-8"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-9">
        <div className="dot dot-9"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-10">
        <div className="dot dot-10"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-11">
        <div className="dot dot-11"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-12">
        <div className="dot dot-12"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-13">
        <div className="dot dot-13"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-14">
        <div className="dot dot-14"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-15">
        <div className="dot dot-15"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-16">
        <div className="dot dot-16"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-17">
        <div className="dot dot-17"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-18">
        <div className="dot dot-18"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-19">
        <div className="dot dot-19"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-20">
        <div className="dot dot-20"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-21">
        <div className="dot dot-21"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-22">
        <div className="dot dot-22"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-23">
        <div className="dot dot-23"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-24">
        <div className="dot dot-24"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-25">
        <div className="dot dot-25"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-26">
        <div className="dot dot-26"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-27">
        <div className="dot dot-27"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-28">
        <div className="dot dot-28"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-29">
        <div className="dot dot-29"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-30">
        <div className="dot dot-30"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-31">
        <div className="dot dot-31"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-32">
        <div className="dot dot-32"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-33">
        <div className="dot dot-33"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-34">
        <div className="dot dot-34"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-35">
        <div className="dot dot-35"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-36">
        <div className="dot dot-36"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-37">
        <div className="dot dot-37"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-38">
        <div className="dot dot-38"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-39">
        <div className="dot dot-39"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-40">
        <div className="dot dot-40"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-41">
        <div className="dot dot-41"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-42">
        <div className="dot dot-42"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-43">
        <div className="dot dot-43"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-44">
        <div className="dot dot-44"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-45">
        <div className="dot dot-45"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-46">
        <div className="dot dot-46"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-47">
        <div className="dot dot-47"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-48">
        <div className="dot dot-48"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-49">
        <div className="dot dot-49"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-50">
        <div className="dot dot-50"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-51">
        <div className="dot dot-51"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-52">
        <div className="dot dot-52"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-53">
        <div className="dot dot-53"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-54">
        <div className="dot dot-54"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-55">
        <div className="dot dot-55"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-56">
        <div className="dot dot-56"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-57">
        <div className="dot dot-57"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-58">
        <div className="dot dot-58"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-59">
        <div className="dot dot-59"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-60">
        <div className="dot dot-60"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-61">
        <div className="dot dot-61"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-62">
        <div className="dot dot-62"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-63">
        <div className="dot dot-63"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-64">
        <div className="dot dot-64"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-65">
        <div className="dot dot-65"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-66">
        <div className="dot dot-66"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-67">
        <div className="dot dot-67"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-68">
        <div className="dot dot-68"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-69">
        <div className="dot dot-69"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-70">
        <div className="dot dot-70"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-71">
        <div className="dot dot-71"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-72">
        <div className="dot dot-72"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-73">
        <div className="dot dot-73"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-74">
        <div className="dot dot-74"> </div>
    </div>
    <div className="dotWrapper dotWrapper-75">
        <div className="dot dot-75"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вряд ли кто сможет ответить на вопрос с такой его постановкой. Что значит прогнать через map? А что должно после этого получиться?

Comment: @ДмитрийЗаварзин Должен получиться именно такой `html` но через `.map()`, сорри если не понятно написал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то должно получиться примерно такое:

```
let data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
let html = data.map(itemValue => {
  return (
    <div className={`dotWrapper dotWrapper-${itemValue}`}>
      <div className={`dot dot-${itemValue}`}> </div>
    </div>
  )
})
```

В переменной html далее будет храниться jsx код, который можно будет вставить куда угодно.

Comment: да, это оно. А как можно оптимизировать `let data`, на тот случай если будет `...1000` ?

Comment: Данный код - никак. Если подразумевается какая-то боле сложная логика для генерации, то можно, но нужен конкретный пример. В нашем случае, даже с 1000 элементами все отработает быстро и не должно возникнуть никаких сложностей с производительностью

Comment: Спасибо, думал просто можно что то типа такого сделать `let data = [1,2,3,...999]`

Comment: Теперь я понял о чем вы говорите. Если необходимо сгенерировать n одинаковых элементов отличающихся порядковым номером, то можно все это сделать с помощью цикла for

Answer (score 0):

```
const length = 999;
const htmlArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
    htmlArr.push(
        <div className={`dotWrapper dotWrapper-${i}`}>
            <div className={`dot dot-${i}`}></div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

С помощью цикла for можно генерировать length-количество JSX элементов в виде массива.